# ScrollTop() always returns 0 after document.location.reload()

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, reload

I've got a page which contains the button that calls document.location.reload() when clicked. When reloading the page I get the value of $(document).scrollTop().

```
$(function(){
  alert("scrollTop:"+$(document).scrollTop()); //or $(window).scrollTop() or $('body').scrollTop()
})
```

In Firefox and Opera scrollTop() returns correct value.
And in Chrome and IE always returns 0.

Example:(http://jsbin.com/ipepon/8)
Steps:

1. close alert
2. Scroll page to the bottom
3. Click on the button

As for Chrome,  I know that the scroll position recovery occurs after loading the document and can be obtained in the Scroll event handler .

Is there any cross-browser way to determine correctly scrollTop value, when you reload the document?

**Update 1**

Solution that works, but it looks "dirty":

```
$(window).load(function(){
  setTimeout(function(){alert("scrollTop:"+$(document).scrollTop());},10);
});
```

(try http://jsbin.com/ipepon/34)
Set the delay for recover the scroll position.

Comment: What do you need to know exactly? The distance from the button to the top?

Comment: I need display popup and for this I need to calculate the value for the top: var top = Math.max($(window).height() / 2 - $("#popup_window").height() / 2, 0) + $(document).scrollTop();

Comment: Can't you use a fixed position for your div instead? If not you could always add a $(window).scroll() to make function trigger first after the page has been scrolled. Then you could add a variable to make sure it only does it the first time. Almost an ugly fix as setTimeout though.